# Increment a value up to a specific value, and then decrement back down to the initial starting point?

Tags: c, loops, counter

Apologies for the title, but I could not find a similar question that has already been posed. As implied, my question is how to implement a counter which starts at an initial value and increments upwards until a specific point is reached, then decrements back down to the original value. Allow me to provide an example to better suggest showcase what I mean

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
      printf("i = %d\n", i);
      if(i == 5) {
          int j = i;
          for(j = i; j >= 0; j--) {
              printf("j = %d\n", j);
          }
      }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When run, the program will print values 0-5 for `i`, then print 5-0 for `j` and then finish printing 6-10 for `i`. Instead of this, I just want to have the program print 0-5 for `i` and then 5-0 for `i` (or `j` if another variable is needed).

Comment: Why do you nest your loops? Why not just `for(i=0;i<=5;i++){ [print] }` then `for(i=5;i>=0;i--){ [print] }`?

Comment: This example is just something to showcase what I was trying to say. In actuality the idea is not utilizing `for` loops and increments a value by 80 until it reaches a point where adding 80 would cause the value to go over a threshold, in which case the value will begin decreasing by 80 and repeat the process

Comment: Did you try to let your first loop iterate till `i < 6`?

Comment: @nice_remark The text in that comment should have been the question. There was no need for the current code in the question, except to serve as an example of what you _don't_ want..

Answer (score 3):

You could use two separate loops like Rafalon in the comments suggested.

If you want one loop you can do something like this (modified it with the information from OPs comment):

```
int ctr_dir = 80;
int upper_value = 500;
for(int i = 0; i >= 0; i += ctr_dir)
{
  printf("%d", i);
  if (i > upper_value)
    ctr_dir = -80;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the benefit of one loop? It is less readable and much slower.

Comment: @Lundin taking the comment from OP into account you have flexibility. You could use a threshold that can be modified by other threads or vary the amount you add/substract easily (or again modify it from another thread to switch directions). Though it is much slower.

Comment: Who said anything about multi-threading or variable limits? That would be another problem entirely. Writing for loops with variable conditions is a bad idea in general. It is better to use while loop for such scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

You are making this needlessly complicated.

```
for(int i=0; i<6; i++) // print 0 to 5
{
  printf("%d\n", i); 
}

for(int i=0; i<6; i++) // print 5 to 0
{
  printf("%d\n", 5-i);
}
```

Comment: My actual problem is more complicated than that. I just put this code down to showcase what the issue is

Comment: Maybe you could explain your real problem a bit more.

Comment: @nice_remark Yes I saw that comment before posting this. Still I don't see why you shouldn't use two simple loops. `while(something) { for(....) {} for(....) {} }`.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I don't fully understand the reasons behind the way you've written the code, the missing ingredient from it is a `break` inside the `if` statement which will exit the loop rather than continuing on and printing out 6 to 10.

```
  for(i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
      printf("i = %d\n", i);
      if(i == 5) {
          int j = i;
          for(j = i; j >= 0; j--) {
              printf("j = %d\n", j);
          }
          break; // Exit the loop
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think simple is best, but you said "my problem is more complex" (I don't know how much more !?), I wrote a more "complex" version...

You can do this something like this,

But the problem with this code is overshoots. i.e. if step is more than 1, you can pass maximum value. :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void WaveGenerator(int start, int step, int max, int times)
{
    int value = start;
    times *= 2;

    printf("%d", value);
    while(times)
    {
        value += step;
        if ((value <= start) || (value >= max))
        {
            step *= -1;
            times--;
        }
        printf("%d", value);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i;

    WaveGenerator(1, 1, 5, 2);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There have been many different solutions here, including the one I already posted as a comment.

Let me add another one here, similar to @izlin's but yet different:

```
int i=0;
int j=0;
int max=10;

for(i=0;i<=max;i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", j);

    if(i<max/2)
        j++;
    else
        j--;
}
// max=10 > 0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0
// max=11 > 0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0 -1
```

Note that depending on the parity of `max`, this will go down to either `0` or `-1`.

---

This can be tweaked this way:

```
int i=0;
int j=0;
int max=10;

for(i=0;i<=max;i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(j);

    if(i<max/2)
        j++;
    else if(i>(max-1)/2)
        j--;
}
// max=10 > 0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0
// max=11 > 0 1 2 3 4 5 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

so it writes the top number twice if `max` is odd, and once if it is even, but always starts and ends with `0`.

---

I would however still use 2 loops instead, as I suggested in my comment:

```
int i=0;
int max=5;

for(i=0;i<=max;i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
// 0 1 2 3 4 5
for(i=max;i>=0;i--)
{
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
// 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the work you want to perform is the same whether you are going up or down, you don't want to use separate loops as you'd be repeating yourself.

You can do this in a single loop by using a flag that indicates whether you've hit the upper limit.  If the flag isn't set you increment, if it is you decrement.

```
int increment = 5, limit = 50;
int i = 0, go_back = 0;

while (i>=0) {
    printf("%d\n", i);

    if (i >= limit) {
        go_back = 1;
    }
    if (go_back) {
        i -= increment;
    } else {
        i += increment;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you can wrap the content in a function and call that function in both loops